# how to access to HTTP session packets in windows server IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, windows-server, httpsession

I need to see all the HTTP sessions and see all the packets for each session coming to IIS. 
I need this cause I want to check all the incoming dbms query requests that will be submitted to database before they got executed.
Do you think what I want to do is feasible? Will the http sessions packets include query information?
How could I achieve my goal and from what should I start?
I tried to search on internet but could not get the proper solutions to the problem. 
I will really appreciate if you can let me know more detailed step by step instruction to achieve my goal.

Thank you

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of application you are using? You can use some tools like performance monitor,iis logs, debug diagnostic tools.this are the tools which is used for monitor iis.To get more detail you need to write your own custom module.

Comment: I just want to get all the session details in C# in real time. any idea to achieve that?

Comment: if you want to get the request detail you can get it by the fiddler or network monitor. you can also check the iis work process detail. and the DBMS query is managed at the application level. i could not understand your requirement clearly.